# How to set server to run the perl script in  "root-directory/sub-directory/cgi-bin" from "root-directory/cgi-bin" in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: php, perl, ubuntu, virtualhost

I am using **PHPmotion** in my local ubuntu machine. **Uber-uploader** is used in phpmotion for uploading files to the server.This is using perl script ( at "**www/cgi-bin**") to uploading files. But in my machine perl script is running fine when PHPmotion is installed in root directory. But when I moved the whole files from  **www** to **www/subdirectory**.Now **uber-uploader** is not running, instead its downloaded. I know the server is not running the PERL scripts in  **www/subdirectory/cgi-bin**. How can I run the PERL scripts that are locating in **www/subdirectory/cgi-bin**.?

Comment: Voting to move to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your webserver configuration files. In case of [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html), you'll probably want to check for the line where `www/cgi-bin` is declared to contain executable scripts, and do the same for `www/subdir/cgi-bin`.

Comment: Yes,Its Now working.I did changes in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file to run PERL in subdirectory. Thank you.